# New Selected Index

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
    public void btnArchive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gvView.DataSource = da.GetArchiveEmp(gvView.Rows[].Cells[2].Text);
        gvView.DataBind();
    }
```

I need to know how to **access** the `selected row` of my `Gridview`,in a `button` not belongs to this `Gridview`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try to rephrase the question as it's unclear as to what you require here.

Comment: well you can click on the row to make it selected to begin with, but whatever you have given in question is not very helpful to understand your problem. maybe you can use rowselection checkboxes.

Comment: all i need is that in gv.View.Rows[] insert the e.NewSelectedIndex method because it is not letting me noticing that its on btnArchive_click. 

if it is on gvDependents_SelectedIndexChanging it will let me ok. Is there any method to insert the .newselectedindex in the gv.View Rows[]???

Comment: : Is this button in your grid view or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `SelectedRow` you can do `gvView.Rows[gvView.SelectedIndex]`

If you want to set a row as selected you can do `gvView.SelectedIndex = row number`

If you want to set one particular cell of selected row as `datasource` you can do

`gvView.DataSource = da.GetArchiveEmp(gvView.Rows[gvView.SelectedIndex].Cells[2].Text);`

Comment: I tried it but it is giving me this error -->> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

by default it is selecting a -1 how can i solve it pls?

Comment: mmm so i need to select that row. the problem is that im working in a button click event. because if im working in a gridview event it will be not a problem. do I can have the possibility to select the desired row in a button click event?

thanks for your patience

Comment: Yes you can. In the event just do `gvView.SelectedIndex = row that you want to be selected`. and remember the index starts from `0` not `1`.

Comment: I have many rows. I think i need to change my structure. Because at the moment i have an edit button in the gridview. Then when pressing it i can change the data but i have an option to show the archives. I need that when clicking the archives button it will return the data of that row in a gridview table. sry if i am not clear.